# Update one table with unique values from another?

Tags: mysql

We started with one table for a project and soon realized we needed multiple tables for what we wanted to do.

We started to switch over, but now I want to get completely switched from one table to multiple.

**What I have now:**

```
TABLE: CONTACT
+-----+-------+--------+----------+
| id  | fname | lname  | phone    |
+-----+-------+--------+----------+
| 123 | John  | Doe    | 555-1234 |
| 124 | Mary  | Shelly | 555-5857 |
| 125 | Jane  | Doe    | NULL     |
+-----+-------+--------+----------+

TABLE: PHONE
+----+--------+----------+------+
| id | con_id |   phone  | main |
+----+--------+----------+------+
| 1  | 125    | 555-5857 | N    |
+----+--------+----------+------+
```

So we have a few that were added and changed. Now, I need to add all the data that isn't already in the PHONE table from the CONTACT table. I do that with a temp table:

```
TABLE: temp
+------------+----------+------+
| foreign_id |   phone  | main |
+------------+----------+------+
| 123        | 555-1234 | Y    |
| 124        | 555-4153 | Y    |
| 125        | 555-5857 | N    |
+------------+----------+------+
```

But when I add from temp to phone, I end up with duplicate entries (in the example, where contact.id = 125).

**This is what I am trying to get to:**

```
TABLE: CONTACT
+-----+-------+--------+
| id  | fname | lname  |
+-----+-------+--------+
| 123 | John  | Doe    |
| 124 | Mary  | Shelly |
| 125 | Jane  | Doe    |
+-----+-------+--------+


TABLE: PHONE
+----+--------+----------+------+
| id | con_id |   phone  | main |
+----+--------+----------+------+
| 1  | 125    | 555-5857 | N    |
| 2  | 123    | 555-1234 | Y    |
| 3  | 124    | 555-4153 | Y    |
+----+--------+----------+------+
```

**Commands I've run:**

```
create temporary table temp (select t2.id, phone from contact t2);
alter table temp add main varchar(1);
update temp set main = "Y";

insert into phone (con_id, phone, main) select id, phone, main from temp;
drop table temp;
```

And eventually, I'll remove the column "phone" from contact. Problem is, if there is already an entry in the table for a phone number, I'm left with duplicates. **How do I prevent that?**

Also, if I'm doing it wrong, I can change that too. I just figured a temp table might be the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid duplicates by adding a primary key (or a unique key) to the phone table:

```
ALTER TABLE phone ADD PRIMARY KEY (con_id);
```

This will ensure that you have only one entry for each con_id. If you want to allow multiple phone numbers for each con_id, you should use instead:

```
ALTER TABLE phone ADD PRIMARY KEY (con_id, phone);
```

Now, you can insert the entries directly from the contact table - or from your temp table, if you have already dropped the phone column in your contact table:

```
REPLACE INTO phone (con_id,phone,main) 
   SELECT id, phone, "Y" FROM contact;
```

Alternatively, you can use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... construction. 
If you don't want to overwrite but keep the original non-primary key values, you could use INSERT IGNORE instead.

For more details about the INSERT syntax, consult: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert.html

Comment: INSERT IGNORE is the way to go I think (there could be multiple phone numbers for one person).

Comment: If there could be multiple phone numbers, then the primary key (or a unique key) should be con_id,phone. If you want to update the "main" field at the same time, you should use "REPLACE", if you want to retain the value in "main", you could ask well use "INSERT IGNORE", which goes faster.

Comment: So I don't need a temp table at all then?

Comment: That's correct, as long as you haven't dropped the phone number column from the CONTACT table, you don't need the temp table. The only new information that is not present in the contact table is the info on whether it's the main phone number of not.